# K&R Exercise 1-18. Remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line

Tags: beginner, c, strings, io

### Intro

I'm going through the K&R book (2nd edition, ANSI C ver.) and want to get the most from it: learn (outdated) C and practice problem-solving at the same time. I believe that the author's intention was to give the reader a good exercise, to make him think hard about what he can do with the tools introduced, so I'm sticking to program features introduced so far and using "future" features and standards only if they don't change the program logic.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99`.

### K&R Exercise 1-18

Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

### Solution

My solution reuses functions coded in the previous exercises (`getline` & `copy`) and adds a new function `size_t trimtrail(char line[]);` to solve the problem. For lines that can fit in the buffer, the solution is straightforward. However, what if they can't? The `main` routine deals with that.

Since dynamic memory allocation hasn't been introduced, I don't see a way to completely trim arbitrary length lines. Therefore, solution does the next best thing: trim the ends, and signal whether there's more job to be done. This way, the shell can re-run the program as many times as necessary to finish the job.

### Code

```
/* Exercise 1-18. Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs
 * from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BUFSIZE 10          // line buffer size

size_t getline(char line[], size_t sz);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
size_t trimtrail(char line[]);

int main(void)
{
    size_t len;             // working length
    size_t nlen;            // peek length
    size_t tlen;            // trimmed length
    char line[BUFSIZE];     // working buffer
    char nline[BUFSIZE];    // peek buffer
    bool istail = false;
    bool ismore = false;

    len = getline(line, BUFSIZE);
    while (len > 0) {
        if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
            // proper termination can mean either a whole line, or end
            // of one
            tlen = trimtrail(line);
            if (istail == false) {
                // base case, whole line fits in the working buffer
                // print only non-empty lines
                if (line[0] != '\n') {
                    printf("%s", line);
                }
            }
            else {
                // long line case, only the tail in the working buffer
                printf("%s", line);
                if (len != tlen) {
                    // we couldn't keep the whole history so maybe more
                    // blanks were seen which could not be processed;
                    // run the program again to catch those
                    ismore = true;
                }
            }
            // this always gets the [beginning of] next line
            len = getline(line, BUFSIZE);
            istail = 0;
        }
        else {
            // if it was not properly terminated, peek ahead to
            // determine whether there's more of the line or we reached
            // EOF
            nlen = getline(nline, BUFSIZE);
            if (nlen > 0) {
                if (nline[0]=='\n') {
                    // if next read got us just the '\n'
                    // we can safely trim the preceding buffer
                    tlen = trimtrail(line);
                    if (tlen > 0) {
                        printf("%s", line);
                        if (len != tlen)
                            ismore = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // if still no '\n', we don't know if safe to trim
                    // and can only print the preceding buffer here
                    printf("%s", line);
                }
                // we didn't yet process the 2nd buffer so copy it into
                // 1st and run it through the loop above
                len = nlen;
                copy(line, nline);
                istail = 1;
            }
            else {
                // EOF reached, peek buffer empty
                // means we can safely trim the preceding buffer
                tlen = trimtrail(line);
                if (tlen > 0) {
                    if (line[0]!='\n') {
                        printf("%s", line);
                    }
                    else {
                        ismore = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (len != tlen) {
                    ismore = 1;
                }
                // and we don't need to run the loop anymore, exit here
                len = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // if there were too long lines, we could not trim them all;
    // signal to the environment that more runs could be required
    return ismore;
}

/* getline: read a line into `s`, return string length;
 * `sz` must be >1 to accomodate at least one character and string
 * termination '\0'
 */
size_t getline(char s[], size_t sz)
{
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    bool el = false;
    while (i < sz-1 && el == false) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            el = true;
        }
        else {
            s[i] = (char) c;
            ++i;
            if (c == '\n') {
                el = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i < sz) {
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy a '\0' terminated string `from` into `to`;
 * assume `to` is big enough;
 */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; from[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
}

/* trimtrail: trim trailing tabs and blanks, returns new length
 */
size_t trimtrail(char s[])
{
    size_t lastnb;
    size_t i;
    // find the last non-blank char
    for (i = 0, lastnb = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\n') {
            lastnb = i;
        }
    }
    // is it a non-empty string?
    if (i > 0) {
        --i;
        // is there a non-blank char?
        if (lastnb > 0 || 
        (s[0] != ' ' && s[0] != '\t' && s[0] != '\n')) {
            // has non-blanks, but is it properly terminated?
            if (s[i] == '\n') {
                ++lastnb;
                s[lastnb] = '\n';
            }
        }
        else {
            // blanks-only line, but is it properly terminated?
            if (s[i] == '\n') {
                s[lastnb] = '\n';
            }
        }
        ++lastnb;
        s[lastnb] = '\0';
        return lastnb;
    }
    else {
        // empty string
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Test

#### Input File

```
1        
2       



444 4                        
5555 5                           
66666 6                                6
777777 7                               
8888888 8                               
99999999 9                               
000000000 0                                   
1
```

#### Test Script (Bash)

```
i=0
j=1
./ch1-ex-1-18-01 <test.txt >out1.txt
while [ $? -eq 1 ] && [ $j -lt 20 ]; do
    let i+=1
    let j+=1
    ./ch1-ex-1-18-01 <out${i}.txt >out${j}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Review covers only minor stuff.

**getline()**

Avoid a technical exploit when size == 0.  Although this code passes sizes more than 0, the function is hackable with size == 0.

When `sz == 0`, as type `size_t`, `sz-1` is a huge value.  Simply + 1 on the left-hand side instead.

```
// while (i < sz-1 && el == false)
while (i + 1 < sz && el == false)
```

**Advanced: getline()**

When a rare reading error occurs, `getchar()` returns `EOF`.  Standard functions like `fgets()` return `NULL` even if some characters were successfully read prior to the error.  This differs from OP's `getline()` functionality.  Since `getline()` uses a return of 0 to indicate end-of-file (and no data read), a parallel functionality to `fgets()` would also return 0 when an input error occurs (even if some good data read prior).

Easy, yet pedantic, change suggested:

```
if (i < sz) {
    // add if
    if (c == EOF && !feof(stdin)) {  // EOF due to error
      i = 0;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
}
```

**Consider `const`**

When the source data does not change, using `const` can make for 1) more clarity in function usage 2) greater applicability as then `const char *f;  copy(..., f);` is possible.  3) potentially more efficient code.

```
// void copy(char to[], char from[]);
void copy(char to[], char const from[]);
```

**Advanced: Consider `restrict`**

`restrict`, roughly, implies that the data referenced by pointer only changes due to the code's function without side effects.  Should `from/to` overlap, `copy()` as presently coded, can dramatically fail.  `restrict` informs the caller that `to/from` should not overlap and thus allows the compiler to perform additional optimizations based on that.

```
// void copy(char to[], char const from[]);
void copy(char * restrict to, char const * restrict from);
```

**Inconsistent documentation/function**

Code is described as "trim trailing tabs and blanks" yet then trims `' '`, `'\t'` and `'\n'`.  Recommended consistent documentation and function.

**Sentinels**

When printing string test output, especially ones with white-space removal, use sentinels to help show problems.

```
// printf("%s", line);
printf("<%s>", line);
```

**`bool` deserves boolean syntax**

Style issue.

```
// while (i < sz-1 && el == false) {
while (i < sz-1 && !el) {
```

---

No major issues noted.  Well done.

Comment: Thanks! So the EOF test is for when just 1 `getchar` call returned EOF, but next call would return something else. Currently my program would still read the partial line, and continue reading after the error. With the fix, it would stop at the error, is that right?

As for the "trim trailing tabs and blanks", if the string had an `\n`, it puts it back at the end, if the string didn't have it (too long line, or EOF-terminated), it doesn't add it.

Comment: @div0man ,"it would stop at the error, is that right? " Yes.

Comment: Great review; should be pointed out that `bool` and `restrict` are a `C99` feature and not `C90`.